# Alter login form redirect doesn't work

Tags: 6, forms, users

I have user login block on custom page, I try:

```
if ($form_id == 'user_login_block') {

    $form['#redirect'] = '/';//or <front>

}
```

But I am redirecting always to the same page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user login block form is a special case.  You will see that in the #action property, it defaults to /node?destination=node.  The "destination" is the important piece, as it will override many of the normal avenues you would take to redirect the form including a $form_state['redirect'] in a submit handler.  The code below is an example of how you can redirect the user_login_block form by modifying the #action property.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ('user_login_block' == $form_id) {
    $path = 'path/i/am/redirecting/to';
    $form['#action'] = url($_GET['q'], array('query' => array('destination' => $path)));
  }
}
```

Also, take a look at hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(), which is the preferred method for altering the form for performance reasons.

Comment: What version does this code apply to, just Drupal 6, or Drupal 7 aswell?

Comment: I tested this out with Drupal 7, but looking at the D6 code the concepts should apply there as well.

Comment: Just to comment on my own code, a better option for building the #action property would be to set it to `url($_GET['q'], array('query' => array('destination' => $path)))`

Comment: Modified code in answer based on my comment in an effort to post code that adheres to best practices.  Sorry about the switch.